# Can you schedule a task to start using timePicker?

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, timepicker

I want to ask is it possible to schedule a task in an Android application using the timePicker Manager? My idea is to start a task at the selected time in the timePickerDialog. If it is possible could you show me how to do it with code?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to schedule a task at certain time of day is using Alarms. They have the advantage that your application does not even have to run at that moment and will be managed by the OS.

The documentation on next link also provides implementation examples: http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html